# SAPUI5: DataBinding to List

Tags: javascript, xml, data-binding, sapui5

I've got this XML list:

```
<List id="myList"
            items="{/Items}">
            <items>
                <ObjectListItem title="{ID}" type="Active" press="onListItemPressed"
                            number="{ parts:[{path:'Price'},{path:'Currency'}],
                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }"
                    numberUnit="{Currency}">
                    <firstStatus>
                        <ObjectStatus
                            text="{path:'End',
                            formatter: '.formatter.getCountdown'}"
                            state="{path:'End', formatter:
                            '.formatter.getCountdownStatus'}" />
                    </firstStatus>
                    <attributes>
                        <ObjectAttribute text="{i18n>GlobalType}: {Format}" />
                    </attributes>
                </ObjectListItem>
            </items>
        </List>
```

At the moment i bind the data with JS:

```
var objectTemplate = new sap.m.ObjectListItem({
                title : "{ID}",
                number : "{ parts:[{path:'Price'},{path:'Currency'}], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }",
                numberUnit :"{Currency}",
                type : sap.m.ListType.Active,
                press : this.onListItemPressed,

                attributes : [new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
                          text : "{i18n>GlobalType}: {Format}"
                    })],
                firstStatus : new sap.m.ObjectStatus({
                                           text : "{path:'End'}",
                                           status : "{path:'End'}" 
                })
            });


oList.bindAggregation("items", {
                path : "/Items",
                filters: [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("Type", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.TypeID ) ],
                template : objectTemplate
      });
```

I would like to use the XML list instead of creating the list by JS. Can i use bindAggregation with an XML Template?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the right way in your first XML view example (you have to bind the `items` property which is done in this example). 
But in this case you have to remove the `<items>` node from the XML view as you want to use a template factory instead of defining items manually.

```
<List id="myList"
        items="{/Items}">
            <ObjectListItem title="{ID}" type="Active" press="onListItemPressed"
                        number="{ parts:[{path:'Price'},{path:'Currency'}],
                        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }"
                numberUnit="{Currency}">
                <firstStatus>
                    <ObjectStatus
                        text="{path:'End',
                        formatter: '.formatter.getCountdown'}"
                        state="{path:'End', formatter:
                        '.formatter.getCountdownStatus'}" />
                </firstStatus>
                <attributes>
                    <ObjectAttribute text="{i18n>GlobalType}: {Format}" />
                </attributes>
            </ObjectListItem>
    </List>
```

Comment: But what i've to do in the controller instead of `template : objectTemplate` ? Can i get the "myList" structure instead? I don't know to use `bindAggregation` with a XML view

Comment: AFAIK it's not supported/recommended to mix these two techniques; however you can try to remove the `template : objectTemplate` part of the JS code, and remove the `items="{/Items}"` binding and `<items>` node from the XML. Why do you want to mix these things? If you want to apply filters in an XML view, check this [example](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm700_ehp03/helpdata/en/09/9f0a2851ad4118af36345f7dd13ea8/content.htm)

Comment: I want to use XML for all views. Now it's a mix. In the XML is an empty List with no attributes and in the controller the list will be filled. :-/

Comment: Yeah, that's we can expect from this, as mixture doesn't seem to be supported in case of binding. With this I'd recommend to move to the XML `view. oList.bindAggregation(..)` from the controller is equivalent to `items="{/Items}"` in the XML view. Do you have any blocks/errors with this scenario?